# How do I fix a 404 Error created through data:image/gif;base64 being added to my site?

Tags: wordpress, base64, http-status-code-404, cloudflare

I have been trying to figure out why each image on my WordPress site is resulting in the following code being changed in all images I upload:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large image-shadow img"><a href="https://www.example.com/blog-post-title/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img width="600" height="400" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/blog-post-title-image-1.jpg" alt="image description" class="wp-image-18844 lazyload" data-srcset="https://i1.wp.com/www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/blog-post-title-image-1.jpg?w=600&amp;ssl=1 600w, https://i1.wp.com/www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/blog-post-title-image-1.jpg?resize=300%2C200&amp;ssl=1 300w" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" /><noscript>
```

This results in Ahrefs scans displaying 404 errors for all URLs; for example, the URL below loads fine, but there is an added /images/gif to the string.

```
https://www.example.com/blog-post-title/
```

becomes

```
https://www.example.com/blog-post-title/images/gif
```

in the Ahrefs report coming from the crawl. It seems from what I have been able to find out that the issue may be coming from here:

```
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
```

I host on SiteGround and use their CloudFlare addon with some settings applied through my CloudFlare account.

Has anyone else encountered these 404 errors? If so, may I ask how they were resolved?

I've experimented with various redirects to the post (which haven't worked and maybe the completely wrong thing to do).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue was triggered by the JetPack Lazy Load settings. These have since been turned off and the issue has been resolved.